# How can I select all records and the match of both tables get in one record

Tags: sql, join

I want to get all the records from two tables, calculating the sum of the amount grouped by day, but showing all the records from both, when the date match show both values.
For example I have:

```
table 1 In
id        ammount           date
1         300               2017-10-25
2         150               2017-10-25
3         550               2017-10-27


table 2 out
1         250               2017-10-27
2         410               2017-10-28
3         830               2017-10-29
```

and I want this result:

```
result
ammount in          ammount out        date
450                 0                  2017-10-25
550                 250                2017-10-27
0                   410                2017-10-28
0                   830                2017-10-29
```

any idea how to make this?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Oracle? SQL Server? PostgreSQL? MySQL? ... Always tag SQL questions with the DBMS you want an answer for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with SQLite3:

```
create table t1(id,amount,date);
insert into t1 values
(1,300,'2017-10-25'),
(2,150,'2017-10-25'),
(3,550,'2017-10-27');

create table t2(id,amount,date);
insert into t2 values
(1,250,'2017-10-27'),
(2,410,'2017-10-28'),
(3,830,'2017-10-29');

select sum(amount_in) as amount_in, sum(amount_out) as amount_out, date
from (
  select amount as amount_in, 0 as amount_out, date from t1
  union all
  select 0 as amount_in, amount as amount_out, date from t2
  )
group by date;
```

Comment: Good idea. This must be `UNION ALL` though. Otherwise you'd involuntarily remove rows with the same amount on the same day.

Comment: Right you are! Corrected.

Comment: yeah thanks it works, just have to get an alias on main select and works fine, really thanks

Comment: For MySQL (and possibly others) you need an alias.  For SQLite3 you don't.

Answer (score 0):

That's a full outer join on the two aggregated tables:

```
select
  coalesce(tin.ammount, 0) as ammount_in,
  coalesce(tout.ammount, 0) as ammount_out,
  date
from            (select date, sum(ammount) as total from table_in group by date) tin
full outer join (select date, sum(ammount) as total from table_out group by date) tout
  using (date);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is works in MS sql server

```
    SELECT     SUM(amount_in) AS amount_in, SUM(amount_out) AS amount_out, date1
FROM         (SELECT     amount AS amount_in, 0 AS amount_out, date1
                   FROM          t1
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT     0 AS amount_in, amount AS amount_out, date1
                   FROM         t2) AS derivedtbl_1
GROUP BY date1
```